# How to make data in jasper report display like list using java?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, try-catch, operator-keyword

I want to display data/value in jasper report from table , in series from first row until last row ..
but i just can display the value that have String type, if the record is BigDecimal or Double, it couldn't work

this is my report shown :

```
 Name       Amount    Price

 dendi      150.0     12.500
 patricia 
 Kelvin 
 Andrew
```

the amount and the price just shown the last record of the table, so what to do, if i call them using parameter in java project like :

```
paramater.put("name",name);
parameter.put("amount", amount);
```

Comment: Could you pls post more information how you are using in the jasper template design. Pls paste the jrxml (as xml).

Comment: @ayyoung What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: As I said just hours ago to someone that I think is you.  If you loop the collection and add each value to the map with an identical key. ***only the last `put` will remain in the map - 'overwriting' all other values".***  Did you delete an earlier question on this?

Answer (score 2):

You may use **[JRMapCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRMapCollectionDataSource.html)** in which each record from your table goes in a Map and every map is added to a collection. If you use parameter it won't repeat for each record.

For example, in your case you can *create a map and a collection of maps*

```
Collection<Map<String, Object>> records = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

Map<String, Object> record1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();

record1.put("Name","dendi");
record1.put("Amount",amount1); //amount1 is a BigDecimal for 150.0
record1.put("Price", price1); // price1 is a Double for 12.500

records.add(record1); // add each record to your map

Map<String, Object> record2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
record2.put("Name","patricia");
record2.put("Amount",amount2); //amount2 is a BigDecimal 
record2.put("Price", price2); // price2 is a Double 

records.add(record2); // add each record to your map
```

*Define* the fields in your jrxml *same as the keys* (Name, Amount and Price - the latter two as BigDecimal/Double types). 
Jasper Reports library would take care of the casting from object to BigDecimal or Double. Hope this helps.

*PS: This code is for illustration purpose only*

Comment: But i used to called the value from table .. 
the column of the table i've called by using parameter,

so , the main direction is i want to call the data record in table and display it to jasper report ...

Comment: From what I understand, you are using the parameter map to get the DB column names and the data from the DB table. Hope you have configured a JDBC datasource to your template. If so, instead of the field name use $P{columnMap}.get("key_for_column_Name") in the detail band. The detail band expects the column name to be retrieved from the datasource. If the datasource is DB then this would work.